# Eva for function prototype returning pointer to array

Tags: frama-c

I have a question regarding using Eva for functions that return pointers,
I am using Frama-C version 23.1 (Vanadium). The issue arises when only the prototype, and not the body, of the function is available, and the assumption is that the function should return a pointer to the beginning of an array. Below is a minimal example:

```
int arr[8];
int x,y;

int *foo();

// int *foo() {
//   return arr;
// }

void main() {
  int *a = foo();

  x = a[2];

  y = 3;
}
```

The analysis stops upon reaching the line x = a[2] and generates the following alarm from the associated memory assertion:

```
alarm: assert Eva: mem_access: \valid_read(a + 2);
Status: **NOT** VALID according to Eva (under hypotheses)

This instruction always fail.
```

If I provide the body of the function (which is commented out in the example), the analysis works. However, I wonder if there is some way to fully analyze this program using Eva, without providing the body, for example by annotating the foo prototype in ACSL. I tried using the allocation clause of ACSL function contracts, but it seems not supported by Eva. Perhaps there is some other annotation that I have not found or some other way of configuring Eva to allow analysis of this program?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: `allocates` is for dynamic memory allocation, which does not happen in your example code. If the original code does involve dynamic allocation, instead of a global array, then for now you'll have to provide a code stub (some simplified code emulating the behavior of the original one). A function whose return value is a chunk of freshly-allocated memory is allowed in ACSL, but currently not supported in Eva.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if you don't want (or can't) provide the body of `f`, Eva will require some additional input, generally under the form of an ACSL contract or by writing a stub directly in C, allowing for a simpler representation than the full-fledged definition (Section 5.4.3 of the [Eva manual](https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-eva-manual.pdf) briefly describes these two points).

If you take the ACSL contract route, you first have to write an appropriate `assigns` clause(s), including the `\from` part, which is needed for Eva to have an accurate view of the dependencies between memory location.

You can also provide `requires` clause, to check that the function is called in a suitable context, and `ensures` clause to be more precise about the value taken by the locations mentioned in the `assigns` clause. In both cases, the ACSL clauses should be interpretable by Eva, otherwise they won't be really useful. Chapter 8 of the Eva manual deals with the handling of ACSL annotations by Eva.

In your particular context, a possible contract for `f` would be the following:

```c
int* b = &arr[0]; // Eva does not seem to appreciate &arr[0] in the \from
/*@ assigns \result \from b;
    ensures \result == &arr[0];
*/
```

Note that `allocates` clauses and `\fresh`/`\freed` ACSL predicates are *not* among the subset of ACSL that is understood by Eva, so that if you want to deal with functions that perform dynamic allocation, you'll need to take the C stub route.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the reply. My hope was that I could write a contract that does not reference the C variable directly, since this is assumed to be not known at verification time. But if that is not possible, your suggestion seems like a good alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is indeed not possible. An important point to have in mind there is that Eva will never use an ACSL clause to create new base address out of nothing. All it does is reducing (when it can) its current state by eliminating the values that would falsify the clause. But it needs to have an abstract value for `\result` in the first place (which is what the `assigns \result \from ...` provides: Eva will assume that the base address of `\result` comes from the `...`